# how to Update SQL in Vb.net using textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

im a total noob here.

i keep on trying to do a basic updating in Vb.net with MS access..so far i made this. it has no errors but it doesnt update my table..instead it deletes whats inside the cell it suppose to update and replace it with an empty cell.

ive been trying all sorts of stuff for the past 9 hours. can someone please throw a stone at me so that i will know where to go next.

```
Private Sub GroupBox2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   GroupBox2.Enter
    dbprovider = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbsource = "Data Source= C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\grocerydb.mdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource

    con.Open()

    sql = "UPDATE items SET Name = @Name where ItemID = 1"
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox31.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    con.Close()
```

PS: my table consist of(just to give you an idea)

```
ItemID    Name    Price
1         bread   5
2         carrots 3
```

Comment: Congrats to using parameterized queries! The code and esp. the query look alright - did you debug to see what's actually in `TextBox31.Text`? Maybe `TextBox31` is not the one you're actually entering data into?

Comment: my textbox31.text is empty..because that where i should type the new input..right?

Comment: Well, if `TextBox31.Text` is empty, it is not very astounding that the value in the database is also empty? Writing an empty string to the database results in the field containing an empty string... What I mean is: Set a **breakpoint** when **running** your application in the line where you add the parameter and when execution stops there, check that `TextBox31.Text` is **not** empty when the query is executed by moving the mouse cursor over the word `Text` in your source code..

Comment: ohhhh i got what the breakpoint is .....i added a button and put that code instead in the button..so  that it will read what i typed when i clicked the button...thank you sir..its working now.

it  automatically reads the empty textbox because i just put the code inside the groupbox containing my textboxes...

Comment: I'll write an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment to you question was:

> The code and esp. the query look alright - did you set a breakpoint to see what's actually in `TextBox31.Text`? Maybe `TextBox31` is not the one you're actually entering data into?

I'm just writing this as an answer here so you can accept, as obviously that solved your problem.